# Jest snapshots for components using platform-specific modules

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, jestjs

When testing a component that differs between platforms, I perform 2 snapshot tests (iOS & Android). When testing for Android, I first set `Platform.OS` to `"android"` before executing the rest of the test. When the component being tested relies on Android modules, like`TouchableNativeFeedback`, the resultant snapshot is an error message:

```js
<View ...>
  <Text ...>
    TouchableNativeFeadback is not supported on this platform!
  </Text>
</View>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to mock it out.

Here is what our mock looks like, in `__mocks__/react-native.js` folder:

```
export * from 'react-native';

export const TouchableNativeFeedback = (touchableNativeFeedback) => {
  const { children, ...rest } = touchableNativeFeedback;
  const combinedComponent = Object.assign(rest, children);
  return combinedComponent;
};
TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground = jest.fn(
  () => 'SelectableBackground'
);
TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackgroundBorderless = jest.fn(
  () => 'SelectableBackgroundBorderless'
);
TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple = jest.fn(() => 'Ripple');
```